# Is it legal if I have 2 Android publisher accounts

Tags: android, google-play

I'm an Android developer and I already have an Android market publisher account. There are a couple of apps in my account.

I have an idea to create a little Android development brand(company)
and publish those new apps in a new publisher account.

So I want to know that is it legal having two Android Market publisher
accounts for the same person. Will I get into any trouble?

Also will Google suspend me if I use push ad networks like Airpush and leadolt?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a problem with an individual having multiple Android Market accounts. Each will need to be tied to a different Google ID (email address). They may also have to be tied to different Google Checkout merchant accounts, although I don't know that for sure.

You cannot publish the same app (as determined by the package name declared in the manifest) on two Android Market accounts. You can ask support to transfer an app from one account to another.

I have no idea about using other ad technologies. I suggest that you ask the Android Market people directly. See [this page](http://support.google.com/androidmarket/developer/bin/request.py?contact_type=contact_policy) for support info.

Comment: thanks for your replay. i asked this question because if i start a business with Android development, i really should know these stuff because my business will be on google's hand. if they ban my account, it will be a huge problem. i read about google banned stories, most of them are not very clear. specially cases like moonbeamdevelopment. i have no reputation to give a vote up. sorry about that :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't think google will block app if you use Third party Ad-Suppliers.

I have been using **TapJoy** Ad service for an year.